# I'm trying to set up the emscripten SDK on Windows 10 but emcc can't be found

Tags: windows, sdk, emscripten

On linux there's no problem but I want to compile my code on windows. I follow the [instructions](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html) exactly. Specifically, I open a command prompt and run the following in the same directory I cloned the emscripten git repo in to.

```
git pull
emsdk install latest
emsdk activate latest
emsdk_env.bat
```

There is suspiciously no output and emcc cannot be found. What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the command line and type `python --version` the version of python installed should come up.

If it doesn't, go to the directory in which python is installed and add this to your PATH.

Restart the command prompt and try `python --version` again. If you get the version of python, follow the [steps](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html) you mentioned.
You should get some output.

Let me know if the problem still has not been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Python 2.7.12 or newer.

https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#windows